# jQuery - How do I add one to a variable when an input is entered?

Tags: jquery, html, input

The code is the following:

```js
 var risk = 0;

if ($('input').val()) {
 risk += 1 ;
}

 if (risk <= 2) {
  $("#riskAssess").append("LOW RISK").css({"color": "green", "font-size": "25px"});
 } 

 else if (risk <= 4) {
  $("#riskAssess").append("MODERATE RISK").css({"color": "yellow", "font-size": "25px"});
 }

 else {
  $("#riskAssess").append("HIGH RISK").css({"color": "red", "font-size": "25px"});
 }
```

```html
<div id="q2">
   <h2>Answer the Following:</h2>
   <div class="grouping"><p><label for="Name">What is your name?</label></p><input type="text" name="Name"/></div>
   <p>Select your age range.</p>
    <div id="age">
    <label for="U13">Under 13</label> <input class="check" type="checkbox" id="U13" name="U13" />
    <label for="13-17">13-17</label> <input class="check" type="checkbox" id="13-17" name="13-17" />
    <label for="18-25">18-25</label> <input class="check" type="checkbox" id="18-25" name="18-25" />
    <label for="26-34">26-34</label> <input class="check" type="checkbox" id="26-34" name="26-34" />
    <label for="35-54">35-54</label> <input class="check" type="checkbox" id="35-54" name="35-54" />
    <label for="55-64">13-17</label> <input class="check" type="checkbox" id="55-64" name="55-64" />
    <label for="64+">Over 64</label> <input class="check" type="checkbox" id="64+" name="64+" />
    </div>
    
   <div class="grouping"><p><label for="Occupation">What is your occupation?</label></p><input type="text" name="Occupation"/></div>
   <div class="grouping"><p><label for="City">What city do you live in?</label></p><input type="text" name="City"/></div>
   <div class="grouping"><p id="placeofbirth"><label for="pob">Where were you born?</label></p><input type="text" name="pob"/></div>
   <div id="button2"><button id="finish">Finish</button></div>
   
  </div>
  
  <div id="qfinal">
   <h2>You are at a <span id="riskAssess"></span></h2>
```

It should add one for each input. Right now it stays the same.

For example, when you answer "What is your name", it should change risk form 0 to 1.

Comment: How do you run the code? It needs to be in an event listener so it runs when the user enters something.

Comment: Can you please include your html? The core of your issue though is that you only run this code on load.

Comment: Should the risk variable increase for every character in the input?

Comment: I included the html. It should increase the risk variable for the whole input not each character.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a event listner on your input.

```
var risk = 0;

$('input').focusout(function(){
  risk++;
  encraseRisk();
});

function encraseRisk(){
  console.log(risk);
  // do something with risk
}
```